# Why are the filters in conv_filter_visualization example 128x128?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

This Keras [conv_filter_visualization](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_filter_visualization.py) example outputs an 8x8 grid of visualized weights for layer 5 of the VGG-16 network. The code goes through 128 of the 512 filters, and visualizes the weights of those which give the highest loss. An output example is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VnoD.jpg).

Why does each cell in the grid have a dimension of 128x128 pixels?

Layer 5 of VGG, has three 512x3x3 filters:

## Block 5

```
x = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block5_conv1')(x)
x = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block5_conv2')(x)
x = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block5_conv3')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool')(x)`
```

I am confused as to how these are visualized as 128x128 pixel cells.

Answer (score 0):

The input to the network is a 128x128 greyscale image, so each cell in the visualization is the result of convolving the test image with one of the filters.
The 64 most discriminative filters are shown.